# Solution to the difference between the big O notation: O(f(n)) - O(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

Well I came across this question in one of the books I was referring.
I am not quite certain as to what this logically implies. 
Neither do I have a solution for any deductions.
How can we use mathematical operations on Asymptotic notations, if so which operations are valid.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh no you didn't. It's "O" not "Oh", it's not surprised - it's measuring the time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`O(f(n))` describes a class of functions so we cannot really make a strong case as to what will be the result of `O(f(n)) - O(f(n))` in general. Notice that we can have many cases like `g(n) - g(n) = 0` or `g(n) - (-g(n)) = 2g(n)` (both equivalent to `O(f(n)) - O(f(n))` since they only differ by a constant factor). At best we can say that  `O(f(n)) - O(f(n)) = O(f(n))`, we will never go beyond that as it would require one of the functions to be bigger than the other one by a non-constant factor (dependent on `n`).

You can also do addition of BigO - the biggest element will always dominate the whole expression for instance `O(n^2) + O(n) = O(n^2)` because BigO simply denotes the upper bound for our complexity.

I don't really see use for subtraction, though.

Comment: here's a use: O(log(m/n)) = O(log(m) - log(n))

Comment: @amit well yes but here you have subtraction inside the BigO, I was more thinking about subtracting two BigO's of the same variable. For addition it makes sense, for instance we have 2 subroutines that run in O(n) and O(n^2) respectively so the total time will be O(n)+O(n^2) but I don't see any use for such subtraction

Comment: O(f(x)) + O(g(x)) is not really defined in all the books I'm familiar with, but I believe you mean O(f(x)) + O(g(x)) = O(f(x) + g(x)), so I see no difference, you can have O(logm)/O(logn) according to this (NON FORMAL) logic

Comment: O(f(x)) + O(g(x)) = O(max(f(x),g(x)) not O(f(x)+g(x))

Comment: @SabirAhmed actually both are equivalent. The beauty of complexity analysis - we can discard a lot of stuff :-)